# Inconsistent check in to SharePoint prompt when closing Word

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, word, check-in

After editing a Word document from a SharePoint 2013 document library, and when closing the application, the prompt for check in is not always present.

This behavior is very inconsistent. Sometimes is shows up, and sometimes it does not. Even on the same document. When the prompt does not appear, the document remains checked out in SharePoint and changes is not visible to other users.

Anyone know why this is happening? Can we force the prompt to show up when closing Word?

Comment: We dealt with this in the past and have just addressed it through business process. My experience is it will not prompt to check in if you open a checked out file and make no changes, but I have heard conflicting reports.